# Could Not pass Android Application moduls Gradel config Android Studio firebase Connection Error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

[This Error Is Coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVli0.png)

Whenever I try To connect Firebase in android studio this error pops us it says

**Error Message**

*Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.*

I have upload the image of Same error I have written no code in it

**Please Help Me It Is Very Frustranting As a new Learnner**

Comment: Try to manually implement firebase by adding dependencies in gradle and google-service.json in your app module package. And if problem arises again, please mention your gradle project and app module file.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.Gradle app change the "compileSdk 32 to 31" and sync - Its works for me on the AS updated version.

android {
compileSdk 31

Comment: "as updated version" but it's a downgrade, why downgrade ? can you [edit] your answer to more explain ?